# Guardar matriz auxiliar en c++

Tags: c++

tengo un problema, estoy queriendo tomar las primeras 3 columnas de las 3 primeras fila  de una matriz, la cual es la siguiente

tengo esta matriz:

```
[3][0][1][2][7][4]
[1][5][8][9][3][1]
[2][7][2][5][1][3]
[0][1][3][1][7][8]
[4][2][1][6][2][8]
[2][4][5][2][3][9]
```

Después quiero tomar las 3 primeras filas y 3 primeras columnas:

```
[3][0][1]
[1][5][8]
[2][7][2]
```

Y las quiero guardar en una matriz auxiliar claramente [3][3]

```
for(int i = 0; i <3; i++) { 
  for (int j =0; j <3; j++) {
           mAux[i][j]=m1[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Y me da este resultado:

```
[3][0][1]
[1][5][8]
[2][7][2]
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, después quiero moverme una columna a la derecha por cada fila y guardar los números es decir:

```
for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
            for (int j =1; j <4; j++) {
               mAux[i][j]=m1[i][j];
            }
        }
```

Para que me de este resultado, el cual es correcto :

```
[0][1][2]
[5][8][9]
[7][2][5]
```

Pero a la hora de mostrarlo tengo que ponerlo de esta forma:

```
 for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            for(int j=1; j<4; j++){
                cout<<"["<<mAux[i][j]<<"]";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
```

No se supone que debería guardarse como ¿j=0; j<3; j++? porque estoy empezando otra matriz, solo le pase los datos?, si lo hago de esta forma

```
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                cout<<"["<<mAux[i][j]<<"]";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
```

me sale esto:

```
[465739776][0][1]
[2][5][8]
[9][7][2]
```

Alguna idea? no entiendo porque sucede, gracias por su ayuda, aquí mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {


    int m1[6][6] = {{3, 0, 1, 2, 7, 4},
                    {1, 5, 8, 9, 3, 1},
                    {2, 7, 2, 5, 1, 3},
                    {0, 1, 3, 1, 7, 8},
                    {4, 2, 1, 6, 2, 8},
                    {2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 9}};


    int mAux[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
        for (int j =0; j <3; j++) {
           mAux[i][j]=m1[i][j];

        }

    }

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
            cout<<"["<<m1[i][j]<<"]";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> No se supone que debería guardarse como ¿j=0; j<3; j++?

Pues viendo el código:

```
for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
    for (int j =1; j <4; j++) {
       mAux[i][j]=m1[i][j];
    }
}
```

Ya te puedo adelantar que no. Si quieres que se guarde en el rango (0,3) entonces no puedes usar los mismos índices en `aux` y en `m1`.

Lo que está pasando realmente es que estás escribiendo en posiciones que no pertenecen al array `mAux`. Este array es de 3x3 y tu estás accediendo a posiciones `[X][3]`, que no pertenecen al array.

Para conseguir tu objetivo tienes que usar dos pares de índices:

```
for (int i1 = 0, i2 = 0; i1 < 3; i1++, i2++) {
    for (int j1 = 1, j2 = 0; j1 < 4; j1++, j2++) {
       mAux[i2][j2]=m1[i1][j1];
    }
}
```

Realmente para este caso particular no te hace falta usar el índice `i2`, pero lo vas a necesitar en el momento en el que desplaces las columnas.

Answer (score 1):

En C++ los índices de formaciones<sup>1</sup> se indexan de cero, pero tú estás indexando desde uno las columnas:

```
for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
    for (int j =1; j <4; j++) {
//              ^ <--- ¡Uno!
        mAux[i][j]=m1[i][j]; cout  << "mAux[" << i << "][" << j << "] = " << m1[i][j] << '\n';
//              ^        ^ <--- ¡Uno!
    }
}
```

Esto provoca que dejes posiciones de tu matriz sin asignar:

```
mAux[0][0] <--- ¡Sin asignar!
mAux[1][0] <--- ¡Sin asignar!
mAux[2][0] <--- ¡Sin asignar!
```

Que además al no haber inicializado la matriz, la primera posición queda con un valor residual de memoria y en consecuencia te imprime ese valor extraño.

Para empeorar las cosas, accedas incorrectamente a tres posiciones que no existen:

```
mAux[0][3] <--- ¡Mal!
mAux[1][3] <--- ¡Mal!
mAux[2][3] <--- ¡Mal!
```

Ya hemos dicho que las formaciones se indexan desde cero, así que las posiciones válidas para `mAux` son `0`, `1` o `2` en cualquiera de sus dimensiones. Si no está sucediendo un desastre es porque el operador de indexado (`[]`) hace aritmética de punteros y la operación acaba aterrizando en memoria válida dos de las tres veces.

Tal y como puede verse en el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (la traducción es mía):

> #### 8.3.4 Arreglos
>
> ...
>
> 7. Se sigue una norma consistente en los arreglos multidimensionales. Si `E` es un arreglo de *n*-dimensiones de rango `i × j × ... × k`, entonces `E` usado en una expresión sujeta a la conversión arreglo-a-puntero (4.2) será convertido a un puntero a un arreglo de (*n*-1) dimensiones con un rango `j × ... × k`. Si el operador `*` es aplicado a este puntero de manera implícita o explícita como resultado de sub-indizar, el resultado es un puntero al arreglo de (*n*-1) dimensiones, que a su vez será convertido inmediatamente a puntero.
> 8. [*Ejemplo*: consideremos
>
>    ```
>     int x[3][5];
>    ```
>
>    Aquí `x` es un arreglo de `3 × 5` enteros. Cuando `x` aparecie en una expresión, es convertido a puntero a (los tres primeros) arreglos de enteros de cinco elementos. En la expresión `x[i]` que es equivalente a `*(x+i)`, `x` es convertido en primer lugar a puntero tal y como se describió; entonces `x+i` es convertido al tipo de `x`, que implica multiplicar `i` por la longitud del objeto al que el puntero apunta, específicamente cinco objetos de tipo entero. El resultado se suma y las indirecciones se aplican para devolver un arreglo (de cinco enteros), que a su vez es convertido a un puntero al primero de los enteros. Si hay otra dimensión el mismo proceso se aplica de nuevo; en esta coasión el resultado es un entero. - *fin del ejemplo*]

Así que por magia y arte de la aritmética de punteros...

- `mAux[0][3]` equivale a `mAux[1][0]`.
- `mAux[1][3]` equivale a `mAux[2][0]`.
- `mAux[2][3]` equivale a `mAux[3][0]` **¡FUERA DE LA MATRIZ!**.

Y es por esto que te *sale bien* cuando **imprimes mal**:

> Pero a la hora de mostrarlo tengo que ponerlo de esta forma:
>
> ```
> for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
>            for(int j=1; j<4; j++){
> //                   ^ <--- ¡Uno!
>                cout<<"["<<mAux[i][j]<<"]";
> //                                ^ <--- ¡Uno!
>            }
>            cout<<endl;
>        }
> ```

Si tu objetivo es tomar una sub-sección de una matriz más grande, lo que debes hacer es trabajar con desplazamientos (*offsets*), te propongo lo siguiente:

```
template <std::size_t tamanyo_grande, std::size_t tamanyo_pequenyo>
void copia(const int (&grande)[tamanyo_grande][tamanyo_grande], int (&pequenyo)[tamanyo_pequenyo][tamanyo_pequenyo], int x, int y)
{
    static_assert(tamanyo_pequenyo <= tamanyo_grande);


    int vertical = y;
    for (auto &fila : pequenyo)
    {
        int horizontal = x;
        for (auto &valor : fila)
        {
            valor = grande[vertical][horizontal++];
        }
        ++vertical;
    }
}
```

La función `copia` recibe una matriz cuadrada de tamaño arbitrario junto a una matriz cuadrada más pequeña y unas coordenadas, copiará los valores de las coordenadas en la matriz más pequeña, así `copia(m1, mAux, 1, 0)` obtendrá la matriz que buscabas.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVLtasIwFP3dPMWFwaw0A7XOOT8Ge46uSIjRBdqka1PRSV993U1S59Q9wCBtck/OOTc5hBfFA8@Y2rbtnVQ8q9cCFlJXphQsfyHEiLzImEGwMuvZrJKfYmXAsJypg15tS6bWgsJfe4X4qAUuXshOyzVwXUgWcq0qA1IZCO@9uJ9cmqXXNe3oJ7@z4ISkt4gX7f106JMjCSrDjOQrVlWiNOG1AhbLq1v154SQwOp3KJCcZbCEw5wEG11CyGqj4X4jMwYz@DkaCbCR07zrUn5qZZxqj6rfsh3LsJiBlaPGiQIPLsF3T05N0@RsFUWpdWrwi6ITAZGGNITYrjmTKnS3ddUwmaQ40PR4jCkMKAwpjCg8URg31DY9IvBIYUrhmQJShh3sSSO3iZS4g71D7P64P@3gsaMiNnGL6dlk7BxGTvPcNPMu0fy13idxisMi/mnkqLe4MxrY9H1k/slc5G1pXdY3lOtsA/c2ua4NLBbQS3p28iRbpz2b6CXnTfVcqLcnw1vE/@JkJCiFqUsFgzlp2vaLbzK2rdoHpC95FI3YNw)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: Gracias @eferion